# Elasticsearch logstash jdbc : datetime column is parsed as text type

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I am importing a table using logstash jdbc plugin and I don't understand why a column is dynamically parsed as tex.

this is my sql column :

```
[DATE_VISA] [datetime]
```

my logstash conf file:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.205;databaseName=myDB;"
          jdbc_user => "user"
          jdbc_password => "pass"
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Program Files (x86)\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\sqljdbc42.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        statement => "SELECT  [DATE_VISA] FROM [dbo].[TABLE] WHERE [DATE_VISA] IS NOT NULL"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { 
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       index => "myindex"
       document_type => "mytype"

    }
}
```

when I request mapping in ES I see that:

```
  "date_visa": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  }
```

If i try to make a map before it raise an error during import.

Do you know what this error happens and how make a filter or a transformation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- have logstash make it a date, using the date{} filter.
- have elasticsearch make it a date, using a template with the 'format' param that matches the value in the database.

Comment: thank you for answere, i saw date filter for parsing logs but i did not see how to do that with jdbc , could you give me a link with an exemple please? it would be very helpful for me

Comment: When your query runs, you should get a field in logstash called something like "date_visa".  Use that as the input to the date{} filter (and probably have it replace the field so it turns date_visa into a date field).